# Show that $Kf(x,y)=\int_0^1k(x,y) f(y) \,dy\\$ is linear and continuous

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $k:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $K:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$, given by $Kf(x,y)=\int_0^1k(x,y) f(y) \,dy\\$. Prove that $K$ is continuous. I try to see continuity in $0$, but i can't find $\delta$.

Comment: use $k \leq C$ for some constant C>0.

Comment: Isnt continuity at one point enough to guarantee overall continuity?

Comment: @Gary. what about step functions?

Comment: @Nameless: I meant for linear operators.

Comment: @Gary. [yeah I guess so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_operator)

Answer (score 4):

let $f\in C[0,1]$ and  $M=\max_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} k$. Then
$$\left|\int_0^1 k(x,y)   f(y) dy\right| \le M \int_0^1 |f|\le M |f|_{C[0,1]}$$
Now take $\sup$ over $x\in [0,1]$. (Note that the map in question is obviously linear)

Comment: over which $x$?, $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: i don't understand this inequality: $M \int_0^1 |f|\le M |f|_{C[0,1]}$

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo, it's actually $|f|_{C[0,1]}(1 - 0)$

Comment: $\int _a^b| f| \le (b-a)  |f|_{C[a,b]}$. Now let $b=1, a =0$

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo $x\in  [0,1]$, of course, that's where the function is defined.

Comment: what $|f|_{C[a,b]}$ actually means?

Comment: @ArielMarceloPardo, sup norm.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, first we show linearity:

$K(f+g)=\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(x,y)dy+ \int_0^1 k(x,y)g(x,y)dy=\int_0^1 k(x,y)(f(x,y)+g(x,y))dy $ , by linearity of the integral.

Then we use 1st countability of $C[0,1]$  (since it is a metric space), and show sequential continuity, which is equivalent to continuity:

Assume $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $C[0,1]$ , so that $Sup |f_n -f|=0 $ . Then

$Kf_n-Kf =\int k(x,y)|f_n-f| dy \rightarrow 0$ , i.e., $Kf_n \rightarrow Kf$